# put value inside Hashmap from another Method inside another Class

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I am trying to create a League of Legend APP. I have a problem that I can not solve. I have declared a Hashmap and ArrayList. First I get data from League of Legend API parsing using JSON. Then I .put the data into Hashmap. However when I try to .put data into Hashmap from another Method in another Class. It does not work.
     `enter code here`if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonData);
                        JSONArray participants = jsonObj.getJSONArray("participants");
                        mourTeamSummonerList = new ArrayList>();
                        menemyTeamSummonerList = new ArrayList>();

```
                    for(int i = 0; i< participants.length();i++){
                        JSONObject p = participants.getJSONObject(i);
                        long teamId = p.getLong("teamId");
                        HashMap<String, Object> participant = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                        if(teamId == 100){

                            long championId = p.getLong("championId");
                            String summonerName = p.getString("summonerName");
                            long summonerId = p.getLong("summonerId");
                            if(summonerName==IDName){
                                ifOurTeam = true;
                            }

                            participant.put("summonerName",summonerName);
                            methods.ChampionSquare(championId, participant);
                            participant.put("summonerId",summonerId);
                            methods.getSummonerInfoFromId(summonerName,participant);
                            System.out.println(participant);
                            mourTeamSummonerList.add(participant);
                        }
                        if(teamId == 200){

                            long championId = p.getLong("championId");
                            String summonerName = p.getString("summonerName");
                            long summonerId = p.getLong("summonerId");

                            participant.put("summonerName",summonerName);
                            methods.ChampionSquare(championId, participant);
                            participant.put("summonerId",summonerId);
                            methods.getSummonerInfoFromId(summonerName,participant);
                            System.out.println(participant);
                            menemyTeamSummonerList.add(participant);
                        }
```

---

```
public class Methods {
public void getSummonerInfoFromId(final String SumName, final HashMap<String, Object> participant) {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/"+SumName.replace(" ","")+"?api_key=7c75d244-fad7-4d18-8038-02a75287fce2")
            .build();

    Call call = client.newCall(request);
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {


        @Override
        public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
            getSummonerInfoFromId(SumName,participant);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {


            try {
                String jsonData = response.body().string();



                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonData);
                    JSONObject game = jsonObj.getJSONObject(SumName.toLowerCase().replace(" ",""));

                    String summonerLevel = Long.toString(game.getLong("summonerLevel"));


                    participant.put("summonerLevel",summonerLevel);


            }
            catch (IOException e) {

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

}
        public void ChampionSquare(final long championId, final HashMap<String, Object> participant) {
    if(championId==1){
        participant.put("championId", R.drawable.annie);
    }
    else if(championId==2){
        participant.put("championId",R.drawable.olaf);
    }
    else if(championId==3){
        participant.put("championId",R.drawable.galio);
    }
    else if(championId==4){
        participant.put("championId",R.drawable.twistedfate);
    }
    else if(championId==5){
        participant.put("championId", R.drawable.xinzhao);
    }
```

When I print out the Hashmap, it prints out partially correct keys and values for summonerName, championId and summonerId. I believe that what I have done wrong is putting key and value inside an innerclass Hashmap:

- {summonerName=whoiam2, championId=2130837580, summonerId=20647588}
  {summonerName=StillHere4U, championId=2130837617,
  summonerId=43639591} {summonerName=StillThere4U,
  championId=2130837564, summonerId=47639078} {summonerName=Kairu
  Rengu, championId=2130837584, summonerId=22276202}
  {summonerName=halmooncircle, championId=2130837573,
  summonerId=31202000} {summonerName=NineWorlds, championId=2130837576,
  summonerId=31544164} {summonerName=Masterzeus92,
  championId=2130837672, summonerId=34979540}
  {summonerName=Feeeeeeeeeeeeesh, championId=2130837577,
  summonerId=27273581} {summonerName=savedolphins,
  championId=2130837664, summonerId=40901971} {summonerName=Lucky
  Th1rt33n, championId=2130837660, summonerId=34587805}

---

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: When I print out the Hashmap, it prints out partially correct keys and values for summonerName, championId and summonerId. Missing summonerLevel key, is it because I am putting key inside an innerclass? and how do i fix it

Comment: What's incorrect about the IDs?

Comment: It should have 4 IDs, summonerName, championId, summonerId and also summonerLevel ID

Comment: Apart from the level being missing, what's incorrect about the IDs and name? You said they were "partially incorrect".

Comment: Oh I see, Sorry about the confusion. The IDs and names are all correct however missing summonerLevel. <--- This is the only error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
new Callback() {


    @Override
    public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
        getSummonerInfoFromId(SumName,participant);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {


        try {
            String jsonData = response.body().string();



                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonData);
                JSONObject game = jsonObj.getJSONObject(SumName.toLowerCase().replace(" ",""));

                String summonerLevel = Long.toString(game.getLong("summonerLevel"));


                participant.put("summonerLevel",summonerLevel);


        }
        catch (IOException e) {

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

does not set the "summonerLevel" key. It creates a `Callback` which, *when its onResponse method is called*, sets the "summonerLevel" key. Then you pass that `Callback` to `call.enqueue`.

Based on the name, I would assume that `call.enqueue` does *not* make the request right away, and so it doesn't call `onResponse` right away, and so the "summonerLevel" key does not get set right away.

At some point later, the call will complete, your callback's `onResponse` method will be called, and you will set the "summonerLevel" key - but that will happen *long after* you've already printed it.

See if there's a way to wait for the call to complete. Then, wait for the call to complete before returning from `getSummonerInfoFromId`.

Comment: Then I believe that I should not request this asynchronously

Comment: Oh my, this really worked, all I had to do was to get rid of call.enque